# Predict live fuel moisture based on NDVI in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I am using the code below to predict live fuel moisture for a specific point, but when I get to getting the value, it says no band 5, but I used band 5 to calculate NDVI, which indicates it is there, even when I buffer the area to 500m it still say to band 5.

Here is the code

```py
# Define the region of interest (samp2)
samp2 = ee.Geometry.Point(25.377865, -25.612602)

# Define the scaling coefficient and y-intercept
scaling_coefficient = -4.3042168674698775
intercept = 1.4847791164658628

# Use Landsat 8 data to calculate NDVI for samp2
landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
samp2_NDVI = ee.Image(
    landsat8.filterBounds(samp2)
    .filterDate('2022-07-06', '2022-07-30')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .mean()
).normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')

# Calculate LFMC based on NDVI
LFMC_samp2 = samp2_NDVI.multiply(ee.Number(scaling_coefficient)).add(intercept)

LFMC_samp2.getInfo()
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your title to use Mixed case. ALL-CAPS is difficult to read and interpreted as SHOUTING (and downvoted)

Answer (score 1):

There are no images from Landsat 8 Collection 1 in your bounds and date range. You can confirm that by checking the `size` of the collection after filtering, before reducing (always a good idea, especially if you run into unexpected errors).

USGS [stopped processing Collection 1](https://www.usgs.gov/news/landsat-collection-1-forward-processing-cease-end-2021) in 2021, and GEE will start removing the collection entirely this year. You can switch over to use [Collection 2](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2) instead using the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/landsat_c1_to_c2#top-of-atmosphere_reflectance).

For this script, all that you'll need to is update the collection ID from `LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA` to `LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA`.

Comment: Thank you Aaron for your response